# Replacement has zero length

Tags: r, for-loop, counting

I have a dataset, `idcredit`, which includes two variables; `PAY_0` and `Default`. `PAY_0` is a factor with inputs `(-2:8)` and `Default` is binary.

I want to count how many times each of the `PAY_0` inputs `Default`. I tried the following for-loop.

```
default.pay = rep(0,11)

for(i in 1:30000)
{
 for(j in -2:8)
  { 
 if(idcredit$PAY_0[i]==j)
   {
    default.pay[j]<-default.pay[j]+idcredit$Default[i]
   }
  }


}
default.pay
```

I get the following error:

```
Error in default.pay[j] <- default.pay[j] + idcredit$Default[i] : 
  replacement has length zero
```

I think it's because my j's start at -2. However I tried adding 3 to each input PAY_0 and it still didn't work.

I seem to have found a work around by using:

```
default.pay = rep(1,11)
```

Although this doesn't actually give the correct answer, it is easily remedied.

Comment: Your example isn't reproducible (we don't have `idcredit`), but you definitely have the problem in using `j` (which takes values from -2 to 8) as an index into `default.pay`, which has indices 1 to 11.

Comment: Is there a way for me to make default.pay have indices -2 to 8?

Comment: `names(default.pay) <- -2:8`, then `default.pay[as.character(j)] ...`

Comment: Using indices "-2" to "8" is a bad idea, because at some point you'll forget the `as.character()`, and just get the wrong value.  Just add 3.

Comment: @user2554330 It also makes the lookup O(N) rather than constant-time.  However, it is "a way" to use negative indices.